# Failed to launch Tomcat 7.X

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

When I launched Tomcat 7.X, I got errors in the console. How can I fix it?

My Server log:

```
August 22, 2016 10:16:15 morning org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
info: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.2 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.2 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.2 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.2 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin;C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\Users\MuteKen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\MuteKen\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\MuteKen\Downloads\Programs;;.
August 22, 2016 10:16:15 morning org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
warning: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ife_service' did not find a matching property.
August 22, 2016 10:16:17 morning org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
info: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
August 22, 2016 10:16:17 morning org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
info: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
August 22, 2016 10:16:17 morning org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
info: Initialization processed in 2895 ms
August 22, 2016 10:16:17 morning org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
info: Starting service Catalina
August 22, 2016 10:16:17 morning org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
info: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
August 22, 2016 10:16:18 morning org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
info: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [468] milliseconds.
August 22, 2016 10:16:18 morning org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
info: validateJarFile(C:\Users\MuteKen\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ife_service\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
August 22, 2016 10:16:23 morning org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
info: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
August 22, 2016 10:16:23 morning org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
info: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Comment: why do you think it is not working?

Comment: because It has no effect when I input localhost:8080 at chrome as usual

Comment: Your log shows very basic warnings. Do you get a 404 error from Tomcat while accessing from the browser . or the regular dinosaur of the chrome browser?

Comment: no any reaction, just like you are offline,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved when I pull the latest code and replace them to the project.
Cause may be that just like warnings I rm the log4j.properies accidentally.
Thk u all to help me :)